# Starting a Form when an Exception occurs

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to show a form (the form has a box where you type in what you were doing to make the error occur, etc. and a send button to report the error to my website) when an unhandled exception occurs. As it is now, the form shows up but none of the controls draw (they are all white boxes) and then I get the "Yaya.exe has stopped responding blah blah blah".

Is there any way to keep the form up while an exception is occurring in the main thread? I've tried putting the form in it's own thread and still not helping. The exception I'm testing this with is a button that starts a backgroundworker, I keep pressing it until it throws the exception which starts the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the contents of your main() method in a try/catch block.  Show your error reporting form, log what you need to, etc. and then die.

This is a good practice regardless.  It really does make the user feel *slightly* better to be presented with something that acknowledges the problem rather than just crashing.  Of course, I say *slightly* better, crashes suck regardless.

Comment: Actualy, you can't wrap Main itself. You mean it's contents.

Comment: This doesn't work out of the box.  There's a default exception handler in the message loop, preventing it from ever getting to the catch clause in Main().  Application.ThreadException is raised.  WPF has a very similar approach, Dispatcher.UnhandledException.  And of course it cannot handle exceptions raised in worker threads.

Answer (score 1):

There is some info on global exception handlers here:

[Uncatchable .NET runtime 2.0 error - user machine - what next?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963542/uncatchable-net-runtime-2-0-error-user-machine-what-next)

Basically, you have to register two events, one for appdomain exceptions, and other for thread exceptions, then implement handlers for them.

Comment: This is how I have it set up, and the handlers launch the error reporting form which doesn't display.

Comment: Hm, what are you doing in your backgroundworker?  If controls doesn't show, it might be a problem with the fact that message pump isn't working any more.